# how to update stored image in oracle

Tags: sql, jsp, oracle10g, blob

i have saved image successfully using column with blob data type

and my table is
studentid varchar2
phoneno number
image blob

my problem is I am unable mage is not getting updated into the database
can you please suggest me the code which updates the image of blob datatype

```
enter code here`



  <%@include file="connection.jsp" %>
  <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <form name="=f1" action="dbupdatedetails.jsp">

       <% 
    String dbeid = request.getParameter("eid");
    String dbimgname = request.getParameter("imgname");
    String dbphno = request.getParameter("phno");


         String path1="C:/Users/sangu/Documents/NetBeansProjects/mini/web/images/"+dbimgname;


    PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement("update  aaa  set PHONENO=?,IMAGE=? where STUDENTID='"+dbeid+"' ");

     ps.setString(1,dbeid);
     ps.setString(2,dbphno);


      File f=new File(path1);
          int s=(int)f.length();
          FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(f);
          ps.setBinaryStream(3,fis,s);
      int k = ps.executeUpdate();
      if(k!=0 )
       { %>
       <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 alert("updated sucessfully");
</script>
   <%}   %>
    %>
    </form>
</body>
```

`

Comment: Your prepared statement only has two `?` placeholders (phoneno and image), but you're setting the first one to dbeid and the second to dbphno. Set placeholder 1 to dbphno and placeholder 2 to the binary stream.

Comment: thank you i have tried this but only phone number field is getting updated image is  not updating .. please fix this

Comment: Please edit your question to show the latest code that you are using.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you showed the code that you're using to do the initial insert.

Comment: PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement("update  aaa  set Studentid=?, PHONENO=?,IMAGE=? where STUDENTID='"+dbeid+"' ");

Comment: and other try was changing the index phone index to 1 and image index to 2